# java commandline argument processing on windows

Tags: java, batch-file, command-line-arguments

I have a java program and want to pass some file paths as command line arguments.
If they contain spaces i have to quote them. This works well for Linux and Windows.
But on Windows, i run into problems if the path contains a trailing slash.

To test this, i wrote a simple [Echo.java](https://github.com/dieterstueken/Echo/blob/master/src/main/java/Echo.java) program.

so, if I say:

java -cp . "C:\Program Files\" "C:\Other Files"

```
[C:\Program Files" C:\Other]
[Files]
```

So, what is going on here? The backslash seems to escape the quote.
For Linux this is OK, but this is on Windows!

but even this:

set PF="C:\Program Files\"

java -cp . "%PF%" "C:\Other Files"

```
[C:\Program Files" C:\Other]
[Files]
```

Without the trailing slash it works as expected:

java -cp . "C:\Program Files" "C:\Other Files"

```
[C:\Program Files]
[C:\Other Files]
```

Comment: correction: I used set PF=C:\Program Files\ without quotes. Adding Quotes makes it even worse.

Comment: an other typo: java -cp . **Echo** "C:\Program Files\" "C:\Other Files"

Comment: A directory path, does not, and should not, end with a trailing backward slash, `\ `. The backward slash is a path separator, if there's nothing to separate, you shouldn't be using it, change the path to `"C:\Program Files"`, you've already done that for `"C:\Other Files"`, so I'm unsure why you have that inconsistency anyhow. Also, you shouldn't define the variable with doublequotes hardcoded into it, you should be using `Set "PF=C:\Program Files"`. Additionally if your path is really that, then why bother defining a variable, `%ProgramFiles%` already exists with the relevant path.

Comment: Simply append a `.` to the directory path, then you do not have to worry about trailing backslashes; this works even when the original path does not have a trailing backslash, without altering its target…

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the path to retrieve files, why not just use forward slashes. It should work. E.g:

```
java -cp . "C:/Program Files/" "C:/Other Files"
```

Comment: sure, you can easily avoid it, but the path values are generated by another batch file using expressions like %~p1. But I just found hint on: https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html

Answer (score 0):

Try C:\Program Files\" with the double slash to escape the slash \ (slash-slash-quote).
Even the text editor here escaped the slash-quote

Comment: my primary question was not how to work around (even this helps, too). Instead I am interested in: why this happens at all?

Answer (score 0):

got a possible solution:

set PF=C:\Program Files\

java -cp . Echo "%PF:\=/%" "C:\Other Files"

```
[C:/Program Files/]
[C:\Other Files"]
```

But my main question was: why this happens at all?

The reason is: On Windows splitting the command line into arguments must be performed by the executable itself (in contrast to Unix). Java7 introduced its [own version](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/windows/native/libjli/cmdtoargs.c) of command line splitting, which behaves differently. It introduces the backslash as an escape character in contrast to the MS setargv.obj solution.

see also: [JDK-8031408](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8031408#linkDescriptionText)

Answer (score 0):

As your issue seems to be that your location with the trailing backward slash, is the result of variable expansion, `%~dp1`, the simplest way to deal with that is to run a command to remove that default trailing character.

Example: *(line `10` is the important part)*

```bsh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Call :Sub "C:\Program Files\Windows NT"
Pause
GoTo :EOF

:Sub
Echo %%1 = %1
Echo %%~dp1 = %~dp1
For %%G In ("%~dp1.") Do Set "PF=%%~fG"
Echo {%PF%}
Exit /B
```